# PHP function to insert html tags before specific characters

Tags: php

I have a challenge where I have some dynamic text which have striped all HTML tags so on my end become a little weird. For example:

*Composizione tessuto: sottoveste: 95% viscosa, 5% elastan, parte superiore: 100% poliestere. Manica lunga Tessuto leggeroColore:BiancoLunghezza:Mini*

In all texts there is Colore and Lunghezza at the end but as you can see it's one word.

What would be the best way to insert HTML tag p before Colore and Lunghezza so it's become more readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to split the string into few parts:

1. before "Colore"
2. "Colore"
3. after "Colore" to beginning of "Lunghezza"
4. "Lunghezza"
5. after "Lunghezza"

And then wrap `1`, `2 and 3`, and `4 and 5` in `<p>` and `</p>`.

```
<?php
$re = '/^(.+)(Colore)(.+)(Lunghezza)(.+)$/m';
$str = 'Composizione tessuto: sottoveste: 95% viscosa, 5% elastan, parte superiore: 100% poliestere. Manica lunga Tessuto leggeroColore:BiancoLunghezza:Mini';
$subst = '<p>$1</p><p>$2$3</p><p>$4$5</p>';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

The result is then

```
<p>Composizione tessuto: sottoveste: 95% viscosa, 5% elastan, parte superiore: 100% poliestere. Manica lunga Tessuto leggero</p><p>Colore:Bianco</p><p>Lunghezza:Mini</p>
```

Live example: https://regex101.com/r/2aGxB0/1

Comment: Wow! Just one question. $str is different for every product, but it has same endind with Colore and Lunghezza. Because there is static text in code, will this work just for exact same texts?

Comment: @Karnak The regex divides the string into parts based on the location of the words "Colore" and "Lunghezza". So as long as the full string contains these words, it will work the same way with other strings. If some don't end with the words, you'll need to create multiple regex patterns to accomodate for different words.